# Testing my list entities to make sure they meet my criteria c#?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have a list which I need to test to make sure they meet the criteria. The list contains numbers. Thew numbers need to be 10 digits long, Only numbers (no letters), not all of the numbers can be the same and null values should be invalid.

Here is the code I am working with.

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
  var testCases = new List<Tuple<String,bool>>() { 
      Tuple.Create("", false),
      Tuple.Create("5875123699", true),
      Tuple.Create("123456", false),
      Tuple.Create("12312312S1", false),
      Tuple.Create("1234567841", true),
      Tuple.Create("12312312312", false),
      Tuple.Create("2222222222", false),
      Tuple.Create("2222222232", true),
      Tuple.Create("-875123699", false),
      Tuple.Create("58751236.9", false),
      Tuple.Create<String,bool>(null, false),
      Tuple.Create("8745102365", true)
  };

  var failed = 0;
  foreach(var test in testCases)
  {
      var result = isValid(test.Item1);
      if(result != test.Item2) {
          Console.WriteLine("Test failed. isValid returned {2} for string {0}. Should be {1}", test.Item1, test.Item2, result);
          failed++;
      }
  }

  if(failed > 0) {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} Tests Failed, Try Again!", failed);  
  } else {
      Console.WriteLine("All tests passed. Well Done.");
  }
```

The tests are:
-The number must be 10 digits long
-no letters, only numbers are allowed 
-you cannot have a number where all of the digits are the same for example 9999999999
-null values should be invalid

I think this project is a little over my head but I will do my best.

Thank you in advance.

SB

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Show your isValid() function

Comment: the isValid function is empty right now

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
public static bool IsTenDigitNumber(string input)
{
    int i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(input, out i))
    {
        if (i < 1000000000)
            return false;
        if (i >= 10000000000)
            return false;
        return (i % 1111111111 != 0);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```